# Error building elephant-bird

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-pig, elephantbird

I'm trying to build Twitter's elephant-bird package so I can use it with Pig, but I'm getting an error:

```
[INFO] Elephant Bird ..................................... SUCCESS [0.638s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hadoop Compatibility ................ SUCCESS [1.213s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Core ................................ FAILURE [0.580s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Cascading2 .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hive ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Mahout .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird RCFile .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Lucene .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig Lucene .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Examples ............................ SKIPPED

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.igor-petruk.protobuf:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.4:run (default) on project elephant-bird-core: Protobuf installation version does not match Protobuf library version -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :elephant-bird-core
```

Here is the maven info for my system:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 09:31:09-0800)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

I've installed Thrift and protobuf already.

**EDIT** Following the advice from Jigar, I fixed the first build error encountered here which had to do with the version of protobuf. I also updated the version number of Thrift in the pom file which was causing an error. But I am still getting the following error:

```
[INFO] Elephant Bird ..................................... SUCCESS [0.647s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hadoop Compatibility ................ SUCCESS [1.157s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Core ................................ FAILURE [7.434s]
[INFO] Elephant Bird Cascading2 .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Hive ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Mahout .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird RCFile .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Lucene .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Pig Lucene .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Elephant Bird Examples ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.987s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 21 14:25:09 PDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/369M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project elephant-bird-core: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/evanzamir/Pig/pig-jars/elephant-bird/core/src/main/java/org/apache/thrift/Fixtures.java:[118,69] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/wiki/Build-errors

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates:

> Protobuf installation version does not match Protobuf library version

You are using the wrong version of protocol buffers. @jigar-joshi posted a pointer to show you how to change it to the right version.

EDIT: The following answers the new error reported by the user.

It is important that you read error messages and try to understand them. For example, this one says:

> /Users/evanzamir/Pig/pig-jars/elephant-bird/core/src/main/java/org/apache/thrift/Fixtures.java:[118,69] error: cannot find symbol

What that means is that in the file `Fixtures.java`, in line 118 (character 69) you have a symbol (for example, variable or method name) that has not been previously defined (or properly imported/properly qualified).

Comment: Thanks, I followed that link and fixed the initial error. But now I am still getting an error. See edited post.

Comment: Thanks @cabad, I did read the error message. It's not my code, so I guess we'll have to blame the folks at Twitter who wrote it. :)

Comment: @evan-zamir hah! sorry about that. In any case, that's what the error means. Why don't you open the file and see what symbol is this? Perhaps you are missing some libraries. You could also try `mvn install ...`.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not a java programmer, which is actually the reason I wanted to use Pig in the first place. LOL All this is pretty foreign to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the workaround. you need to install protobuf 2.4.1 and thrift 0.7.0. I have created presentation with steps to follow(on how to install older versions). Hope this would help

http://www.slideshare.net/kapildewade/elephant-bird-build-error